# How to segment x axis in ggplot 2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table with 16k rows, where I made a graph in ggplot with it. But the subtitles are many and I would like to show only a part of them in a uniform range.

```
elevation<-read.csv("http://wesleysc352.github.io/perfil_elev_miranda.csv", sep=";", header = TRUE)%>%
  as.data.frame()%>%
  mutate_at(c('distancia', 'cota'), as.numeric)%>%
  mutate(dist_km=((distancia)/1000))%>%
  mutate_at(vars(dist_km, distancia), funs(round(., 2)))

ggplot(elevation, aes(x=as.factor(dist_km), y=cota))+
  geom_point(size=0.1, color="red")+
  ggtitle("Profile Elevation river")+
  xlab("Dist(km)")+
  ylab("Elevation(m)")+
  theme_light()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=13))+
  
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))+
  
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(0,555, by=50))
```

I tried to use the following command `scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(0,555, by=50))` to segment every 50 km but it didn't work, because the intervals were not uniform and it doesn't even show the last distance 555km.

[image]

Comment: Why are we converting numeric into factor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for. If you want to have x-axis from 0 to 550 at 50 interval, you don't need to set `dist_km` to factor. Then use `scale_x_continuous` for setting `breaks`.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(elevation, aes(x=dist_km, y=cota))+
  geom_point(size=0.1, color="red")+
  ggtitle("Profile Elevation river")+
  xlab("Dist(km)")+
  ylab("Elevation(m)")+
  theme_light()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=13))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,555, by=50))
```

[image: continuous_x_scale]